# What's wrong with beans binding

Tags: java, user-interface, data-binding

I am starting work on a project that has some code written in BeansBinding.  It seems to work, but I found this scary post: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/fabriziogiudici/archive/2009/03/lets_fork_beans.html

It appears that development on BeansBinding has stopped.  Why wouldn't this ambitious developer just pick up where the other developers left off?  Why is it necessary to fork?  Are there some serious core issues with BeansBinding?

I have not used the BetterBeansBinding yet.  Will projects written in BeansBinding need to be replaced with "BetterBeansBinding" in the future?  Is BetterBeansBinding even somewhat similar to BeansBinding and is it stable?  If BeansBinding is seen as "abandonware" then will BetterBeansBinding have the same fate?

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to hit any the bugs in beans binding (most of the people don't) maybe you will be forced to use betterbeansbinding (where they may have fixed it).

BetterBeansBinding in a drop-in replacement for beansbinding, it has the same api so it's ok to just replace the beansbinding.jar with the betterbeansbinding.jar. It's stable yes.

JSR-295 itself was marked as inactive so it could be that better beans binding share the same fate.

But giving the fact that beans binding was stopped on 2007 and people still use it (netbeans) I don't think you should be scared to use it.