# Why is the BeansBinding jar still not updated?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jform-designer, beans-binding

Why is the widely distributed `BeansBinding` jar version still `beansbinding-1.2.1.jar`?

It can be downloaded from Maven Central, or with Netbeans distributions, 
or installed by the JFormDesigner plugin. Why doesn't it contain the latest changes made in 2008?

For example, the performance issue with many bindings was resolved 10 years ago (see [GitHub `JFormDesigner/swing-beansbinding` commit log from 2008](https://github.com/JFormDesigner/swing-beansbinding/commit/5f188348abb2679809001b9e7429ed722574e940)
).

One discussion about that issue can be found at [BeansBinding Performance (Issue 37)](http://blog.marcnuri.com/beansbinding-performance-issue-37/).
The solution was to remove unneeded `IGNORE_ALL_BEANINFO` in `Introspector.getBeanInfo()` calls.

But `beansbinding-1.2.1.jar`, which is widely distributed, still has the old byte-code in it. What causes that bug to arise again and again?

Comment: Have you looked into the [`BetterBeansBinding`](https://github.com/stephenneal/betterbeansbinding) project? Related StackOverflow question from 2009: [What's wrong with beans binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200828/whats-wrong-with-beans-binding)

Comment: @JonnyHenly Know about it. But it is not distributed instead of `beansbinding-1.2.1.jar` with Netbeans. I suppose the trouble with BeansBinding is the version tag wasn't changed after last code changes and so new code wasn't mavenized/netbeanized.